# Unsuccessful Python reconstruction of original data from PC scores exported from R

Tags: python, r, numpy-ndarray, pca, svd

I am trying to restore original data through PC scores and eigenvectors in python2.7 based on the code [here](https://github.com/harrymatthews50/Modelling_Craniofacial_Growth_Trajectories).

I used the iris dataset from R:

```
# R code ##########################
library(writexl)
pcafast <- prcomp(iris[,1:4])
# Export iris data
write_xlsx(iris[,1:4], "data.xlsx")
# Export PC scores
write_xlsx(as.data.frame(pcafast$x), "score.xlsx")
# Export eigenvectors
write_xlsx(as.data.frame(pcafast$rotation), "eigvec.xlsx")
```

I then try to reconstruct the original iris data using PC scores and eigenvectors calculated within Python2.7 (Method 1) as well as exported from R (Method 2).

Method 1:

```
# Python code ##########################
import numpy as np
import pandas as pa

Y = pa.read_excel("/home/yangjianLab/wenyifeng/pca/data.xlsx")
Y = Y.values

#mean centre
Ymean = np.mean(Y,axis=0)
Y0 = Y - Ymean

# get eigenvectors (v)
u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(Y0)

# project to principal components
PC_projections = np.dot(v,Y0.T).T

ced = np.dot(PC_projections,v)
Yrecon = ced + Ymean
```

Method2:

```
# Python code ##########################
Y2 = pa.read_excel("<PATH>/data.xlsx")
Y2 = Y2.values

#mean centre
Ymean2 = np.mean(Y2,axis=0)

# Load PC scores exported from the prcomp function in R
PC_projections2 = pa.read_excel("<PATH>/score.xlsx")
PC_projections2b = PC_projections2.values

# Load eigenvectors exported from the prcomp function in R
v2 = pa.read_excel("<PATH>/eigvec.xlsx")
v2b = v2.values

ced2 = np.dot(PC_projections2b,v2b)
Yrecon2 = ced2 + Ymean2
```

The original data is successfully reconstructed using Method 1 but not Method 2:

```
>>> Y[:5,:]
array([[ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
       [ 4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2],
       [ 4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2],
       [ 4.6,  3.1,  1.5,  0.2],
       [ 5. ,  3.6,  1.4,  0.2]])
>>> Yrecon[:5,:]
array([[ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
       [ 4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2],
       [ 4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2],
       [ 4.6,  3.1,  1.5,  0.2],
       [ 5. ,  3.6,  1.4,  0.2]])
>>> Yrecon2[:5,:]
array([[ 4.82160564,  1.53318858,  5.50784929,  2.13656975],
       [ 4.66166081,  1.18998229,  5.16178376,  1.97266203],
       [ 4.81972253,  1.0530219 ,  5.34327719,  2.08806774],
       [ 4.93222065,  1.01118633,  5.20921471,  1.92187145],
       [ 4.92871018,  1.4840311 ,  5.5818687 ,  2.16173496]])
```

To explore why, @Seb reminded me 2 issues:
(1) the PC scores from within Python2.7 (Method 1) (`PC_projections`) and from prcomp in R (Method 2) (`PC_projections2b`) **differ by the** **sign of column 1**. (2) Eigenvector `v` from Method 1 is the **transpose of `v2b` from Method 2 plus reversing the sign of row 1 of transposed `v2b`**:

```
>>> PC_projections[:3,:]                                                                                             
array([[ -2.68412563e+00,  -3.19397247e-01,   2.79148276e-02,                                                        
          2.26243707e-03],                                                                                           
       [ -2.71414169e+00,   1.77001225e-01,   2.10464272e-01,                                                        
          9.90265503e-02],
       [ -2.88899057e+00,   1.44949426e-01,  -1.79002563e-02,
          1.99683897e-02]])

>>> PC_projections2b[:3,:]
array([[  2.68412563e+00,  -3.19397247e-01,   2.79148276e-02,
          2.26243707e-03],
       [  2.71414169e+00,   1.77001225e-01,   2.10464272e-01,
          9.90265503e-02],
       [  2.88899057e+00,   1.44949426e-01,  -1.79002563e-02,
          1.99683897e-02]])

>>> v
array([[ 0.36138659, -0.08452251,  0.85667061,  0.3582892 ],
       [-0.65658877, -0.73016143,  0.17337266,  0.07548102],
       [ 0.58202985, -0.59791083, -0.07623608, -0.54583143],
       [ 0.31548719, -0.3197231 , -0.47983899,  0.75365743]])

>>> v2b
array([[-0.36138659, -0.65658877,  0.58202985,  0.31548719],
       [ 0.08452251, -0.73016143, -0.59791083, -0.3197231 ],
       [-0.85667061,  0.17337266, -0.07623608, -0.47983899],
       [-0.3582892 ,  0.07548102, -0.54583143,  0.75365743]])
```

Q1: Are PC scores from Method 1 **always** the same as those from Method 2 except for opposite signs of column 1? Similarly, are eigenvectors from Method 1 **always** equal to the transpose of eigenvectors from Method2 + reversing signs of row 1 of transposed eigenvectors from Method2?

If the differences in PC scores and eigenvectors from svd in Python2 and prcomp in R is ALWAYS as we see above (assuming same centering, scale, and tolerance arguments), I can write a code in R to transform output from prcomp to the desired format. However, **if the differences vary depending on dataset, could anyone please write a code that changes the format of output from prcomp function in R so that when imported into Python2, I could ALWAYS successfully reconstruct original data using the above Python code.**

I do not pursue identical numeric results from both methods, I just wish to make clear when it is necessary to reverse the sign and when it it necessary to transpose so that I get meaningful reconstructed data in Python based on output from prcomp in R.

I am naive to Python so I wish to do all operations in R so that all I need to deal with Python is to import the data and run the code. A big thank you!

Q2: Although original data are reconstruted through Method 1, `np.array_equal(Y[:5,:], Yrecon[:5,:])` surprisingly returned a FALSE. Why?

Comment: `PC_projections` and `PC_projections2b` are not actually close in value (the signs are flipped in the first column). And the eigenvectors are not similar at all.

Comment: Thank you @Seb. I have updated my questions accordingly. Appreciate if you could help.